# Setting property with 'this.' expression for Master-Detail View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to achieve Master-Detail View based on a JSON file. The PHP functions well. It brings the data as it is supposed to be. Config.js, or controller.js are working fine. However, I am getting an error as shown below. The SET property is undefined.

I am a beginner. I thought putting 'this.___ ' would be setting the property. But, it seems that I am missing. If not, what could be wrong?
I took the reference from the below link.

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong? Perhaps, how to set the property?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('myProject', []);
    app.service('ProjectService', function($http) {
        $http.get("projects_read.php", {})
            .then(function(response){
                var pjts = response.data;
                this.getProjects = function() { //ERROR occurs
                    return pjts;  
                };

                this.getProject = function(id) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < pjts.length; i++) {
                        if (pjts[i].id === id) {
                            return pjts[i];
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                console.log(pjts);
            });
    })
})();
```

[ERROR]
Cannot set property 'getProjects' of undefined.

[Reference Link]
http://plnkr.co/edit/VJxlqguJZGrIutAFLCNc?p=preview

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're setting the property `getProjects` on the wrong context (`this`)

The callback `function(response){}` creates a new context (in strict mode is undefined that's why you get: Cannot set property 'getProjects' of undefined) try saving a reference of the service outside the promise and use that context.

```
app.service('ProjectService', function($http) {
    var _this = this; //save context of the service
    $http.get("projects_read.php", {})
    .then(function(response){
        var pjts = response.data;

        _this.getProjects = function() {
          return pjts;  
        };

        this.getProject = function(id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < pjts.length; i++) {
            if (pjts[i].id === id) {
            return pjts[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
        }
        console.log(pjts);
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It worked! Hope this helps the others! :)

Comment: you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Karim also points out you can solve it by using "var _this = this"

Another solution is to bind this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('myProject', []);
    app.service('ProjectService', function($http) {
        $http.get("projects_read.php", {})
            .then(function(response){
                var pjts = response.data;
                this.getProjects = function() { //ERROR occurs
                    return pjts;  
                };

                this.getProject = function(id) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < pjts.length; i++) {
                        if (pjts[i].id === id) {
                            return pjts[i];
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                console.log(pjts);
            }.bind(this));
    })
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It also works! I think I need to see more about this kind of function in the future if possible. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) "This" in javascript and its context can be very confusing, but it's an important concept to grasp.